# Update non-fillable field in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have my User table, the default table laravel comes with when you do the whole `php artisan make:auth` stuff, and I've added a boolean `system_admin` column, and a couple other similar columns

Now when someone registers to the site, I don't want a malicious person to be able to just give themselves that right, so I haven't put that field in the `fillable` array in the User.php model file.

First question then: is that the right decision for the right reason?

But now I'm working on a system admin page, which should allow people to modify properties like that, but in my route, that's only accessible by SystemAdmins, I have code that looks like this:

```
public function updateUser($userId, Request $request) {
        $user = User::find($userId);
        $update = $request->all();
        $user->update($update);
```

And of course, because those columns aren't `fillable`, this request doesn't work for those fields.

But I want it to, because this particular route is protected by middleware that verifies a system_admin should have access to it.

So how do I update these non-fillable columns, without allowing nonSysAdmins to update the same columns?

Comment: `$user->field = $value; .... $user->save();`

Comment: @lagbox brilliant, BUT if 'field' is variable, or worse, there might be multiple fields, what do I do then? Eg I'm trying to update both 'system_admin' and 'client_admin' (another property on my User model), how would I code that so it can iterate over all variable properties provided in the request?

Comment: you probably shouldn't be iterating, you should know exactly what fields you are setting in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used lagbox answer to come up with an alternative solution that goes over every updating variable key in my route:

```
public function updateUser($userId, Request $request) {
    $user = User::find($userId);
    $update = $request->all();
    foreach($update as $key => $value) {
        $user->$key = $value;
    }
    $user->save();

    $newUser = User::find($userId);
    return response()->json($newUser->toJson());
}
```

I'm hoping there's nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: Why aren't you using route binding (automatically initialize the object based on the route) or are you and I'm just not familiar with the syntax?

Comment: @TedStresen-Reuter I had previously tried to use route binding on a different project and it didn't work for me -- I do'nt know if I had some obscure setting in my php/laravel wrong, but it just wasn't working. Once I gave up on it, I actually decided I preferred explicitly getting my objects rather than using clever features of Laravel which can sometimes make certain things too opaque for my liking

Comment: Understood re route binding. Personally, I feel it is worth learning to master as it is a central Laravel feature and really does make things easier (but I do understand the initial resistance!)

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't put that field in the fillable array in the User.php model file

Yes, that is the right decision as it requires you explicitly set that value. That said, it *can* still be set explicitly in code (which is probably what you want).

> So how do I update these non-fillable columns, without allowing nonSysAdmins to update the same columns?

I'm unfamiliar with the `update()` method. Also, normally, Laravel uses something called route binding that automagically initializes an object in the controller based on the route (but that's not crucial to your issue).

Your controller code should look something like this:

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
    $user->fill($request->all());
    $user->system_admin = $request->system_admin;
    $user->save();
    …
}
```

Note that unless you add fields to $fillable you'll have to specify each field you want to update manually (as shown). Looping through the keys is problematic as there may be all kinds of fields that shouldn't be a part of the saved model.

Since you are using guards (or similar) to limit who has access to those routes, it shouldn't be a problem to make system_admin fillable.

HTH

Comment: Thanks @lagbox. You're right. I've updated the example to clarify that point (before you posted your comment :-)

Comment: @TedStresen-Reuter this line, `$user->system_admin = $request->system_admin;`, this bothers me. The request may not contain `system_admin` at all, so what happens in that case?

Comment: And the case that there's other things that are also non-fillable, that aren't system_admin?

Comment: Well, I think that normally you would be using different controller methods (a good idea based on this exact situation) but in the case of missing values, they are simply saved as empty or null, which I think is fine if I've understood your situation.

Comment: If 'system_admin', for example, were missing, I wouldn't want the update to change 'system_admin' on the database at all. I'd want it to change only the properties I sent up.

Comment: So, are you using the same controller method for different forms? I think that a common scenario is that the role is pre-filled with the value that comes from the DB. Thus, when the form is submitted, it contains whatever value was already in the DB (and unless you change it, it doesn't change) but if you're using the controller for different forms, I can see where the issue would be.