# Update non fillable field in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fillable

I would like to import data from an old database, so I would like to fill some fields such as `password`. The `User` model looks like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'disabled_at'
    ];
}
```

In my migration I have:

```
class ThumbnailSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        foreach(User::all() as $user) {
            $user->password = get_old_password($user->id);
            $user->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because Laravel think I am doing Mass assignment...

What should I change to make this work?

I've looked at other similar question such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59425127/2612235) one, but I still not figured out how to bypass Laravel protection.

Comment: You need to  user_id and old_passoword value

Comment: Actually I'm surprised your code doesn't work. Mass assignment means, that you are passing an array of values to the create function ?!

Comment: this code should work, it is not a Mass assignment, i even made a unit test to test it, and everything works fine

Comment: I feel more like you're doing something equivalent to  `$user->password = User::find($user->id)->password;` which won't change anything. Can you share `get_old_password` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier You were right this was an X-Y problem... I was updated the table without populating it before...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using [`forceFill`](https://www.mike-griffiths.co.uk/blog/laravels-forcefill-and-forcecreate/).

```
foreach(User::all() as $user) {
    $user->forceFill(array('password ' => get_old_password($user->id));
    $user->save(); //Not sure if this is necessary
}
```

<sup>This is untested code.</sup>

Comment: The answer is "yes" for the comment you made (without `save()`, the update does not take effect)  and it's not mentioned in the documentation, AFAIK.

Comment: `$user->save();` is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As I suggested in the comment;
I feel more like you're doing something equivalent to

```php
foreach(User::all() as $user) {
    $user->password = User::find($user->id)->password; 
    $user->save();
}
```

which won't change anything.